# C# Show terminal output in program window & respect control characters

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program that will execute another command line application and show it's output in a scroll view text field. I want the same output as you'd get in the terminal, I'm capturing the data using `Process.OutputDataReceived` and `Process.ErrorDataReceived` and appending all those those to the text field with a new line character.

For the most part it works. But the application uses control characters to rewrite bits of the output (for text based progress bars and timers and such). Is there anyway I can use the output from those events to continuously update and modify the text in the box to match what the terminal would actually show?

I tried appending each, line by line and stripping out the non printable characters, but it's not really representative of the realtime output of the program